# Question field in the user registration process

Tags: users

I am wondering if there is a module which would enable asking users why they want to join a site - i have a very small forum and want to avoid spam bots.
I am using captcha and require administrative approval for a new user but I would like to have a field which asks "why would you like to join this forum?" and have that display somewhere that I can see it before enabling the account.
Does anyone have any advice?
Thanks,
Amy

Answer (score 1):

Go to admin/config/people/accounts/fields and add the field. In field settings enable "Display on user registration form." - you can hide it everywhere else if is only for your eyes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to follow your advice but am not able to- does this require a specific module?

Comment: nope, this works right out of the box :-)
You do use Drupal 7, right?

Comment: You have to go to the Configuration tab.
Then choose People.
Then choose settings. 
On the the following page there is a "Manage Fields" tab, click this and create your fields.